# How to inject dependencies if your module itself take parameters in as a constructor?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have just learned about Dependency injection (DI) and I am beginning to like it. To inject dependencies I am using Google Guice framework. Everything was running conceptually fine but while writing a module a thought came to my mind that what if my module require dependencies as a constructor, after all, it is just a class extending AbstractModule.
So, basically, I have 3 modules as a whole.

- Environment Module

  ```
  public class EnvModule extends AbstractModule {
        @Override 
        protected void configure() {
        install(new Servicemodule());
      }
  }
  ```
- ServiceModule

  ```
  public class ServiceModule extends AbstractModule {
     private final boolean isEnabled;
     @Override 
     protected void configure() {
     if (isEnabled) {
     install (new ThirdModule());
     }
  }
  ```

  - ThirdModule (It does not take any arguments in any constructor and have some bindings of its own)

---

Basically, the variable in the service module defines whether my application needs to install the third module or not. And that variable is defined in an application configuration file. So how do I inject that variable in the ServiceModule? As the field is final, setter injection is not possible, is there a way to use construction injection or field injection to inject the value.

Comment: You can have your own parameterised constructor in the Module class and pass in the boolean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the following options:

- Use system variable:

  `ServiceModule() {isEnabled = System.getProperty("isThirdModuleEnabled")};`
- Read the config file directly in the ServiceModule() constructor
- Use @Provides:

  `class ServiceModule ... {
       @Provide @Singleton ThirdModuleParam getThirdModuleParam(...) {
            //read the config file
            ThirdModuleParam res = new ThirdModuleParam();
            res.setIsEnabed(...);
            return res;
       }
   }
   class ThirdModule {
        @Provide SomeThirdModuleClass getIt(ThirdModuleParam param) {
             return param.isEnabled() ? new SomeThirdModuleClass() : null;
   }`